# I am moving elements around depending on screen width using jQuery, but it is creating duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is not something I'm actually going to use, I know I should not have two headers on a page, this is just an example of my problem.

This works perfectly when there is only one  on the page, but when there are two it constantly duplicates the list items. What is causing this? Am I using the (window).resize function incorrectly?

https://jsfiddle.net/ozmay3um/

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Page One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page Two</a>
                <ul class="subpages">
                    <li class="subpage">Subpage One</li>
                    <li class="subpage">Subpage Two</li>
                    <li class="subpage">Subpage Three</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page Three</a></li>
        </ul>      
    </nav> 
</header>

$(document).ready(function() {  

  if ($(window).width() <= 991) {
    // if on load window is smaller than 992px, add subpages to main nav
    $('.subpage').appendTo('.nav');
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
      // if window is larger than 992px, add subpages to sub nav
     $('.subpage').appendTo('.subpages');

    } else {
      // otherwise add to main nav
      $('.subpage').appendTo('.nav');

    }
  });

});
```

Comment: It's totally acceptable to have _several_ `<header>` elements on a page. You could have, for example, many articles on a page, each one with `<header><h3>...</h3><span class="byline">...</span></header>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not operating on each header individually so it actually moves items from one header to another (showing duplicates).  You can change your code to only operate on each header i
individually.

You could do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
      // if window is small than 992px, add subpages to sub nav
        // otherwise add to main nav
        $('.subpage').each(function() {
            $(this).closest(".nav").find(".subpages").append(this);
        });

    } else {
        // otherwise add to main nav
        $('.subpage').each(function() {
            $(this).closest(".nav").append(this);
        });
    }
  }).resize();

});
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/s7fpqfys/

This code finds the parent `.nav` item and then finds the right place to append the subpages within that particular `.nav` hierarchy.  This keeps the reorganization local to the particular `.nav` hierarchy and won't move items between headers.

P.S. I also think you had your `>=` backwards.  I assume you want to use the subnav only when the window is narrow, not when it's wide.

And, I removed the duplicate code that runs initially by instead just triggering the first `resize()` event to force the initial layout.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do but it seems duplicated because the number of $('.subpage')'s you are trying to append are doubled. Below is just taking your code slicing the first half of the results.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  

  if ($(window).width() <= 991) {
    // if on load window is smaller than 992px, add subpages to main nav
    $('.subpage').slice(0, 3).appendTo('.nav');
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
      // if window is larger than 992px, add subpages to sub nav
     $('.subpage').slice(0, 3).appendTo('.subpages');

    } else {
      // otherwise add to main nav
      $('.subpage').slice(0, 3).appendTo('.nav');
    }
  });
    
});
```

```css
header {
    background: black;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: #FFF;
}
.nav li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.nav li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;  
    background: red;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Page One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page Two</a>
                <ul class="subpages">
                    <li class="subpage">Subpage One</li>
                    <li class="subpage">Subpage Two</li>
                    <li class="subpage">Subpage Three</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page Three</a></li>
        </ul>      
    </nav> 
</header>

<header>
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Page One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page Two</a>
                <ul class="subpages">
                    <li class="subpage">Subpage One</li>
                    <li class="subpage">Subpage Two</li>
                    <li class="subpage">Subpage Three</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page Three</a></li>
        </ul>      
    </nav> 
</header>
```